# Replace div with another if data-rel numbers are in order

Tags: jquery, fade, replacewith

I have a puzzle created and I want it to `fadeOut` and the entire image to `fadeIn` when the puzzle is finished correctly, I have added a `data-rel` with numbers to each piece of the puzzle in html so that I can somehow find out when the puzzle is correctly completed but I have no idea on how to do this.

I think I can use something like `replaceWith` like so:

```
$( this ).replaceWith( "<div>" + "my-full-image-source" + "</div>" );
```

**But how do i trigger this only if the data-rel numbers are in order?**

**Here is my html :**

```
<div id="shell">
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="10">10</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="1">1</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="4">4</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="7">7</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="11">11</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="2">2</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="5">5</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="8">8</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="12">12</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="6">6</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="9">9</div>
    <div class="puzzle" data-rel="3">3</div>
</div>
```

**And the script:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#shell').sortable({cursor: 'move'});
});
```

Also the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brilliancedisplay/gtFMD/embedded/result/) for easier understanding.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/gtFMD/2/

Approach is to store the solution as an array of `data-rel` . And get the array of sorted item's `data-rel` in the `update` function of `sortable`. And then compare those two arrays/ If they are equal then you can do the necessary changes/ modifications.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var key = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]; //Answer
    $('#shell').sortable({
        cursor: 'move',
        update: function (event, ui) {
            var numbers = $('.puzzle[data-rel]').map(function () {
                return parseInt($(this).attr('data-rel'));
            });
            console.log(numbers);
            if (key.equals(numbers)) {
                alert('done'); // Your code here
            }
        }
    });
});

//For array comparison.
Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {
    if (!array) return false;
    if (this.length != array.length) return false;
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {
            if (!this[i].equals(array[i])) return false;
        } else if (this[i] != array[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

For array comparison: [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/comparing-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: Wohoo, great answer and of great use. Thanks a lot, fast and right on target. This will do the trick for me, thanks again. Will mark it as soon as stackoverflow will let me :)) I have to wait again, 5 minutes apparently, I would also give you an Upvote but I can't considering that I have not got 15 reputation yet.

Anyway, have a great day.

Comment: Thanks. Great day to you too!